# How do I use instagram-private-api to create groups and send messages

Tags: api, instagram

I tried using the api implementation provided by instagram-private-api and the response was fine with no error, but the recipient was not notified

```
const groupThread = await senderItem.ig.direct.createGroupThread(['58723232', '58660213', '52838612312']);
const thread = senderItem.ig.entity.directThread(groupThread.thread_id);
const msgResult = await thread.broadcastText(text);
```

The msgResult response normally returns the same message as the dm, but the receiver does not receive it. Why?